# List retrieving data from firebase is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm trying to fill a List with data from Firebase database using the function _get_icons(), but I don't know why, when the function ends, the List is still empty (I call the function on initState()). I'll really appreciate your help!

Here is the part of the code that matters:

```
class body_get_poducto extends StatefulWidget {
  bool isAdmin;
  List alergenos = [];
  QueryDocumentSnapshot producto;
  body_get_poducto({Key? key, required this.producto, required this.isAdmin, required this.alergenos}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<body_get_poducto> createState() => _body_get_poductoState();
}

class _body_get_poductoState extends State<body_get_poducto> {
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  
@override
  void initState() {
    _get_icons(widget.producto);
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
            ),
        child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.network(
            widget.producto.get('imagen'),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 16.0 * 1.5),
          Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0,
                  16.0 * 2, 16.0, 16.0),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0 * 3),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(12.0 * 3),
                ),
              ),
              child: 
              Column(
                 mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      
                        Text(
                          widget.producto.get('nombre'),
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                        ),
                      
                      const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                      Text(
                        "\$" + widget.producto.get('precio_estimado').toString(),
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text("Libre de:"),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 20,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          child: 
                          ListView.builder(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                              return Image.asset('assets/'+widget.alergenos[index]+'.png', height: 50, width: 50,);
                            },
                            itemCount: widget.alergenos.length,
                          ),
                        )
                    ]),
                  ),
                  (...)
```

Here is the _get_icons() function:

```
void _get_icons(QueryDocumentSnapshot producto) async {
for(var e in producto.get('alergenos')){
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("Alergenos")
    .doc(e)
    .get()
    .then((value) => widget.alergenos.add(value.get('icono')));
}
widget.alergenos.forEach((element) {print(element);});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your list stays empty is that you don't call a `setState` when adding the value.

```dart
setState(() => widget.alergenos.add(value.get('icono')))
```

I would opt for a list inside your state rather than changing the widget's list.

I also see an issue with your initState method, you start with your own method, but as the docs mention, you should always start with `super.initState()`.

> Implementations of this method should start with a call to the inherited method, as in super.initState().

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! You're right :)